# "which I gave to you or which I gave you"

Tags: direct-objects, object-complements

> ***Where are the flowers which I gave to you?***

or

> ***Where are the flowers which I gave you?***

I can subconsciously choose the latter, but isn't there any grammatical rule that could cover this topic?

I think that "to" preposition can be dropped in either example and thus both of which are correct...

Comment: Better option: "Where are the flowers I gave you?" Using "which" is overkill, and wouldn't normally be used in speech.

Comment: I agree with you, but is my point correct?

Comment: Since it is perfectly OK to say "I gave the flowers to you", there's nothin wrong with the preposition. It is also OK to remove it because you can say "I have you the flowers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in thinking the preposition should be dropped.  The sentence remains clear regardless, but you're best-off eliminating the unnecessary "to".

Along the same line of thought, you can also eliminate "which".  Again, the sentence will remain grammatically correct and clear in meaning.  In general, "which" is used to further describe a noun in the sentence when there is already a complete thought.